# How to disable 'Docs' tab in storybook?

Tags: storybook

How do i disable the 'docs' (addons-docs) tab on a per story basis?

I've tried adding the key values below to a story, but nothing seems to work.

```
parameters: {
  docs: { disable: true, hidden: true }
},
```

I'm running Storybook 5.3.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to do it with the `v6.0.0-alpha.28` (`@storybook/*@next`) with the new parameters:

```
  previewTabs: {
    docs: { hidden: true },
  }
```

I've added the default config on `preview.js`:

```
addParameters({
  previewTabs: {
    docs: {
      hidden: false
    },
    canvas: {
      title: 'Story',
      hidden: false,
    },
  },
})
```

and also repositioned the Docs to be the first tab on `manager.js`:

```
import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';

addons.setConfig({
  previewTabs: {
    'storybook/docs/panel': { index: -1 },
  },
});
```

Hope it works on the long term :)
Enjoy!

Answer (score 13):

This will hide docs panel and show canvas only:

```
  parameters: {
    previewTabs: {
      'storybook/docs/panel': {
        hidden: true,
      },
    },
  },
```

Tabs container will be hidden, if you have only one tab

Comment: Be aware of by hiding the "Docs" panel, when navigating from the docs path from a different component, user wouldn't have a way to view the "Canvas" on the target component, as the link is not changed: `http://localhost:6006/?path=/docs/foo`

Comment: @Downhillski is correct, but it's possible to avoid this by setting `viewMode: 'story'` in `parameters`, as shown in [the Docs recipe "Controlling a story's view mode."](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/761501bf1344c5bab34e881702cc1938557b611c/addons/docs/docs/recipes.md#controlling-a-storys-view-mode)

Answer (score 10):

Inside your *MyStory.stories.j[t]sx* file

To hide the **"Docs"** tab:

```
export default {
    title: 'YourTitle',
    parameters: {
        previewTabs: {
            'storybook/docs/panel': { hidden: true }
        },
        viewMode: 'canvas',
    }
};
```

To hide the **"Canvas"** tab:

```
export default {
    title: 'YourTitle',
    parameters: {
        previewTabs: {
            canvas: { hidden: true},
        },
        viewMode: 'docs',
    }
};
```

The `viewMode: 'docs/canvas'` it's necessary to set the default tab in that view, otherwise storybook will show the last tab opened in the previous view.

Comment: I had to use `story` instead of `canvas` for `viewMode`.

Answer (score 7):

Old Answers give you the technique to hide the `docs` but if someone will change the URL from story to docs, it will show the results, so I am giving you the way to perfectly `remove` the docs tab.

**1st Method**

If you added the `@storybook/addon-docs` package to your `package.json` and added it into `.storybook/main.js` ( addon array ) then remove it and `restart` your storybook webpack server.

**2nd Method**

In the latest version of the `storybook`, it recommends to add an `essentials` addon package coming from `storybook` that contains multiple addons such as `actions, backgrounds, controls, docs, viewport, toolbars`.

So if you installed that package and added it into the `.storybook/main.js` addon array then you disable it with the below code.

Replace your code from

```
module.exports = {
  addons: [
    ...,
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
  ],
};
```

TO

```
module.exports = {
  addons: [
    ...,
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-essentials',
      options: {
        docs: false,
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Hi Nisharg, your answer will completely hide the `docs` tab in the stories. However, the questions asks for removal of `docs` tab on an individual story.

Comment: @SaiNikhil yes you are right but I posted here because if in the future someone wants that answer so her/she can find it easily

Comment: For removal of docs tab on an individual story see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67002340/2307317

Answer (score 0):

Now if you're using storybook 7, you just remove this line in your `*.stories.ts` (I use typescript) file : `tags: ['autodocs'],`. It will disable and hide the docs for the story.