# Hide Docs tab in Storybook

Tags: storybook, mdxjs

I want to create stories using both Typescript and MDX, therefore I have in my `main.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.(mdx|ts)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-docs', 'storybook-addon-preview']
};
```

However I don't want to have "Docs" tab next to "Canvas". How do I remove it? Without `'@storybook/addon-docs'` MDX story is not displayed.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60897150/1241287

Comment: Perfect Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66188323/8798220

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in `preview.js`:

```
export const parameters = {
  previewTabs: {
    'storybook/docs/panel': {
      hidden: true
    }
  }
};
```

Used in Storybook version 6.0.x

Comment: This also works for individual stories. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using `@storybook/angular@6.0.21` and the previous answer unfortunately did not work for me. I was able to find a [solution in the storybook DocsPage documentation](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/master/addons/docs/docs/docspage.md#replacing-docspage).

The relevant section:

```
You can replace DocsPage at any level by overriding the docs.page parameter:

- With null to remove docs
- With MDX docs
- With a custom React component
```

I was able to completely remove the DocsPage for a single story like this:

```js
export const myStory = () => ({
  moduleMetadata: MODULE_METADATA,
  component: MyComponent,
});
myStory.parameters = {
  docs: { page: null },
};
```