# Disable canvas per story in storybook 6

Tags: storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I am trying to find a way to disable canvas at a story level in the new storybook 6. I am making a library of components and, depending on the story, some of them will only have canvas, while others will only have docs.

I have tried using

```
myStory.parameters = {
  previewTabs: {
    canvas: {
      hidden: true,
    },
  },
};
```

or

```
myStory.parameters = {
  previewTabs: {
    'storybook/docs/panel': {
      hidden: false,
    },
  },
};
```

depending on the story. However, this leads to no tab name being shown. As a result of this, the following happens:

1. I have story 1 - only canvas visible
2. I have story 2 - only docs visible
3. I click on story 1 - I see the canvas, as expected
4. I click on story 2 - I see the canvas also, even though it is hidden (I suppose because the tab has been kept from the previous story). As if this is not bad enough, I cannot even click on docs, since no tab name is visible.
5. Same is valid for the reverse (if I start with story 2)

As a workaround for docs, I have found this (thanks  to [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722367/benjamin), in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499683/hide-docs-tab-in-storybook)):

```
myStory.parameters = {
  docs: { page: null },
};
```

With this, I can still see both canvas and docs tabs, but the docs one is now empty for the story where this parameter has been set.

I am looking to do something similar for canvas, and have tried

```
myStory.parameters = {
  canvas: { page: null },
};

myStory.parameters = {
  canvas: { disabled: true },
};
```

but have not worked.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know if this solution will fit your needs, but the workaroud I found was to write my stories in `.mdx` and disable canvas on `Meta`:

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

<Meta
  title="Section/MyComponent"
  parameters={{
    viewMode: 'docs',
    previewTabs: { 
      canvas: { hidden: true } 
     },
  }}
/>

# My markdown title

<Canvas>
  <Story name="mycomponent">
    <MyComponent />
  </Story>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: I don't think that's a workaround. I think that's the preferred solution, though you should probably do it in the global parameters within SB's preview.js file

Answer (score 11):

Yes the tabs are saved from the previous story, but you can set a default view mode for that story, that should solve your problem.

```
myStory.parameters = {
  previewTabs: {
    canvas: {
        hidden: true,
    },
  },
  viewMode: 'docs',
};
```

More examples on
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/master/addons/docs/docs/recipes.md#controlling-a-storys-view-mode

Comment: thanks for the snippet it worked as it is. Another question, the link that you shared it does not show this hidden. For example I need to hide notes and docs under specific stories. Do you also have any idea for these?

Comment: @AlpSenel you should no longer use addon-notes it is deprecated and has been replaced by addon-docs. It is also not possible to disable notes for specific stories as they do not use preview tabs. If you want to migrate from addon-notes to addon-docs you can have a look at a code snippet via the following link:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/addons/docs/docs/recipes.md#migrating-from-notesinfo-addons

Further information you will find here:
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#deprecated-addon-info-addon-notes

Answer (score 2):

Inside your *MyStory.stories.j[t]sx* file

To hide the **"Canvas"** tab:

```
export default {
    title: 'YourTitle',
    parameters: {
        previewTabs: {
            canvas: { hidden: true},
        },
        viewMode: 'docs',
    }
};
```

To hide the **"Docs"** tab:

```
export default {
    title: 'YourTitle',
    parameters: {
        previewTabs: {
            'storybook/docs/panel': { hidden: true }
        },
        viewMode: 'canvas',
    }
};
```

The `viewMode: 'docs/canvas'` it's necessary to set the default tab in that view, otherwise storybook will show the last tab opened in the previous view.